# Rails capybara selenium element not not clickable because another element obscures it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, capybara

I am a struggling to find the right syntax to select an option in a dropdown list using rails/capybara/selenium for testing purpose. Here are the inspect output of the HTML page

```
<select id=”select_test” name=”select_test”>
  <option value =””>Month</option>
  <option value =”1”>January</option>
  <option value =”9”>September</option>
</select>

<button type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" data—id="select_test" title="Month">
  <div class="filter-option">
    <div class="filter-option-inner">
      <div class="filter-option-inner-inner">Month
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
</button>
```

I have tried two approaches:

Approach 1:

```
find(‘[title=Month]’).click
find("[value='9']").click
```

Approach 2:

```
Select 'September', from: select_test, visible: :all
```

Both approach gives me the error

```
Element <select id='select_test' class="" name=select_test"> is not clickable at point (189,175) because anohter element <div class="filter-option-inner-inner">obscures it
```

Anyone would have seen this before and coul help me find the right syntax?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your HTML the value attribute of the element with text "September" is "9" so the correct CSS would have been `option[value=’9’]`, however you really should be using `select` in this case. You're getting the `undefined local variable variable` error because you need to pass a string to `from` rather, otherwise ruby interprets it as you trying to call a method which isn't defined

```
select 'September', from: 'select_test'
```

Comment: Thank you. I have already tried the select / from approach but it gives me the error unable to find a visible select box "select_test" that is not disabled. If I add the argument visible: :all, then the select box seems to be found but I get the error the error element select_test is not clickable because <div class="filter-option-inner-inner"> obscures it. I was actually trying to circumvent this issue with the hereabove approach. I have updated the question to reflect your suggestions. Thanks again.

Comment: @Bastien Are you using a UI library that hide the standard select elements and replace them with styled ul/li, etc widgets? If so you’d need to interact with the replacement HTML elements like a user would